# How could I bind a chess piece to its path?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, chess

I want to be able to place a Queen on the board, and easily remove it, then place it again somewhere else. But I'm running into a few problems. I created a CSS class for adding a Queen to the board, and a class for adding the Queen's path to the board.

The problem I'm having is when I remove the Queen from the board and it's path still remains on the board. So I then need to remove its entire path. See below:

I inserted an 'X' image to visualize all of the Queens paths. I removed the Queen on 5th row, but it's path still remains:
[image]

So, I start by removing its horizontal and vertical path, but I end up removing the path of other Queens in the process... I still have to remove the Queen's diagonal path, but this method is obviously not working well.
[image]

There must be a better way to approach this issue. Any ideas? Bear in mind I'm a newb, and I'm trying to build my first algorithm (a 'N Queen' algorithm).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var queenCount = 0;
  var lastRow = 0;
  var lastCol = 0;
  var lastQ = 0;

  $("li").each(function() {

    if ($(this).hasClass("queen") == false &&
        $(this).hasClass("x") == false) {

      //add queen
      $(this).addClass("queen");
      queenCount = queenCount + 1;

      //queen's horizontal path
      $(this).prevAll().addClass("x");
      $(this).nextAll().addClass("x");

      //queen's vertical path
      var index = $(this).index() + 1;
      $(this).parent("ul").nextAll("ul")
        .children(":nth-child("+index+")").addClass("x");
      $(this).parent("ul").prevAll("ul")
        .children(":nth-child("+index+")").addClass("x");


      //queen's diagonal path
      var cross = index + 1;

      $(this).parent("ul").nextAll("ul").each(function() {
        $(this).children(":nth-child("+cross+")").addClass("x");
        cross = cross + 1;
      });

      cross = index + 1;
      $(this).parent("ul").prevAll("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).children(":nth-child("+cross+")").addClass("x");
        cross = cross + 1;
      });

      cross = index -1;
      $(this).parent("ul").prevAll("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).children(":nth-child("+cross+")").addClass("x");
        cross = cross - 1;
      });

      cross = index -1;
      $(this).parent("ul").nextAll("ul").each(function(){
        $(this).children(":nth-child("+cross+")").addClass("x");
        cross = cross - 1;
      });

      //memorize the last queen's path

      lastCol = $(this).index() + 1;
      lastRow = $(this).parent("ul").index() + 1;
      lastQ = this;

    }
  });


  //remove last queen
  $("ul:nth-child("+lastRow+")")
    .children("li:nth-child(" + lastCol + ")")
    .removeClass("queen");
  queenCount = queenCount -1;

  //remove horizontal range;
  $(lastQ).prevAll().removeClass("x");
  $(lastQ).nextAll().removeClass("x");

  //remove vertical range
  var index = $(lastQ).index() + 1;
  $(lastQ).parent("ul").nextAll("ul")
    .children(":nth-child("+index+")").removeClass("x");
  $(lastQ).parent("ul").prevAll("ul")
    .children(":nth-child("+index+")").removeClass("x");

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: brown;

}

li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}

.queen {
  content: url("http://i.imgur.com/GAOSgVZ.png");
}

.x {
  content: url("http://i.imgur.com/DGocFZb.png");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF;"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black;"></li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
    <li style="background-color:black"></li>
    <li style="background-color:#FFF"></li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Chess has already been invented.

Comment: I lol'd. I'm doing this for practice because I'm an uber noob.

Comment: Most n00bs start with something easier like blackjack or tic-tac-toe. Use a table instead of a list for the board. Assign an id for each cell. Create a 2 dimensional array to control the cells. Any move can now be directed by the matrix generated by the 2d array.

Comment: How do you decide to create the path in the first place? Doesn't seem to be based on game play. I think you really want [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

Comment: give each piece a random class. when adding paths, also add this random class to the pieces paths. when removing, simply remove all elements of that class. generating a random unique class is pretty simple with recursion. google "random string javascript" and you're halfway there.